# Include ant modified selector based on condition

Tags: if-statement, ant, ant-contrib, fileset

I am modifying my exiting ant script to support differential builds. For that I have used modified selector in fileset for finding only modified files. But the problem is when I am doing full build I need to bypass modified filter based on some property or param. As shown below. Is there anyway to do that.

```
<project name="test" default="dt" basedir=".">
    <target name="dt1">
        <copy todir="ant_temp2">
            <fileset dir="ant_temp1">
                <if>
                    <equals arg1="${ABC}" arg2="true" />
                    <then>
                        <modified update="true" />
                    </then>
                </if>
                <exclude name="*.txt"/>
            </fileset>
        </copy>
    </target>

    <target name="dt">
        <antcall target="dt1">
            <param name="ABC" value="true" />
        </antcall>
    </target>

    <target name="dt2">
        <antcall target="dt1" />    
    </target>
</project>
```

If I invoke the above ant script using `dt` target then I need to consider `modified` and the `exclude` in `fileset` task. If it is invoke using `dt2` then I need to consider only `exclude` in the `fileset` task.

I am not able to use the above script beacuse `fileset` does not support nested `if` task. That's why I am looking for alternative way to do this. Please suggest some ways to do this.

P.S: I don't want to create the two targets with the same copy task  one with including `modified` and `exclude` in `fileset` and another target with only `exclude` .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have used below ant script to achieve my requirements.

```
<project name="test" default="dt" basedir=".">
    <patternset  id="fs1">
        <exclude name="*.txt"/>
    </patternset >

    <target name="dt1">
        <copy todir="ant_temp2">
            <fileset dir="ant_temp1">
                <patternset refid="fs1" />
            </fileset>
        </copy>
    </target>

    <target name="dt3">
        <copy todir="ant_temp2">
            <fileset dir="ant_temp1">
                <modified update="true" />
                <patternset refid="fs1" />
            </fileset>
        </copy>
    </target>
</project>
```

I have created reusable pattern set and developers will update their exclusions in that pattern set and i am reusing that pattern sets for normal and incremental builds.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `if` and `unless` attributes on [targets](http://ant.apache.org/manual/targets.html) to make their execution conditional on a property. You should move the conditional part to its own target (if not already done) and then add an `if` or `unless` condition to the target.

I'm not completely clear from your example, but this might mean having the `copy` in two targets, including the `modified` part in only one of them. In that case, you could make each target conditional on the same property - one as `if` the other as `unless`.

Comment: Hi sudocode, Thanks for the help, but I don't want to create a two targets with copy task one contains `modified` and `exclude` and other contains only `exclude` because this is existing script and developer will regularly add more `exclude`s. If I make two targets then they have to add `exclude` in two places.